# Mysql and php error. Strange query behavior

Tags: php, mysql, apache

OK so i have some php code written out like this:

> Database.php

```
<?php 
class Database
{
    protected $__link;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->__link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db", 'pw','user');
    }
    public function getUsernameForBot($id)
    {
        if (mysqli_ping($this->__link)) {
            printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
        } else {
            printf ("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($this->__link));
        }
        //Get list of used usernames.
        $__query = "SELECT *
                    FROM users
                    WHERE users.user_id NOT IN
                    ( 
                        SELECT bot_uname
                        FROM bots
                    )" or die(mysqli_error($this->__link));
        $__result = $this->__link->query($__query);
        echo $this->__link->error;
        $__usernames = array();
        while ($__row = $__result->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($__usernames,$__row);
        }
        foreach($__usernames as &$_user)
        {
            //TODO: do some checking on the users time.
            $_userid = $_user['user_id'];
            $__query = "UPDATE bots
                        SET bot_uname = $_userid
                        WHERE bot_id = $id;" or die(mysqli_error($this->__link));
            $__result = $this->__link->query($__query);
            echo $this->__link->error;
            return $_user['user_name'] . "/" . $_user['user_pass'];
        }
    }
    public function closeConn()
    {
        $this->__link->close();
    }
}
$mydb = new Database();
?>
```

and i have 2 MySQL db listed out like this:

the bots database

```
int(11)    int(11)
bot_id     bot_uname
0          -1
```

and the users database

```
int(11)    varchar(32)   varchar(32)
user_id    user_name     user_pass
0          someuser      somepass
```

and in another php file ill have somethign like this written out.

> index.php

```
<?php
include("Database.php");
echo $mydb->getUsernameForBot(3);
$mydb->closeConn();
?>
```

now the anticipated results of this is the web page looks like someuser/somepass
and the contents of the bots database is changed to reflect that it is using that username.
and it works. sometimes.

i have no idea why, but sometimes it will just up and stop working.
no changes to the code, nothing.
as you can see i included a connection test to see if my link was being closed before i used it, its not.

i also have error outputs to check if there is any mysql errors.
there issent.

i checked the return size of the query, sometimes its the correct amount, sometimes its 0;

iv restarted apachi and mysql.
no change.

im extremly frustrated to check my code over and over and over, watch it work, and then a few minutes later, it will just stop. no warning. no nothing.

edit::remove the ;; in the query, no change.

edit::tried changing the the thing from static to nonstatic, no change.

Anyone got an awnser?

Comment: Why is everything `static`?  That's your problem.

Comment: im pretty sure `$this/self` is out of context when called statically try instantiating the class instead

Comment: @developerwjk ok, ill start chaingin it to not be static,

Comment: @developerwjk after changing everything from static to non static, worked for 2 minutes, then stoped again.
updateing post.

Comment: Is there some error when it stops working? If you invoce the code via apache, check in the apache error.log file.

Comment: @Antoan Milkov there was no errors directly related to it in there, but i did see some other errors, after goggling I re-installed WAMP, and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: @StevenVenham I am glad that my comment lead to the solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a problem with wamp itself, after re-installing wamp, the problem no-longer occurs.